# How to save android text entered by the user?

Tags: android, save

For my newest app it it one that will save multiple EditTexts where the user can enter stuff.Like say if it was a note app,how would i get them to save?

Comment: There is a notes app in the SDK samples. It may requre mountaineering a learning curve but it will be worth learning.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple ways to store data on Android. Read about [data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

In your case you might have multiple text records with some metadata (time when created, etc..), so I'd recommend the database.

Comment: I have read the data storage,but im fairly new to android and i dont know what to do when it comes to saving data.

Comment: You read the documentation and start writing some code. If you have problems you come back here with concrete questions or errors.

Comment: It also helps to google for some examples or tutorials: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidSQLite.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out how to store preferences with android's "SharedPreferences":

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html

This way you can indefinitely store whatever you're working with as a string, object, etc. Also, you can check out how to work with android's SQLite Database, which might be harder to figure out when you start working with it, but it gets easier over time.

Comment: You can not put `Object` into shared preferences: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html